# "%%" and "%/%" for the remainder and the quotient

Tags: r

I am wondering how and why the operator `%%` and `%/%` are for the remainder and the quotient.

Is there any reason or history that R developer had given them the meaning they have?

```
 > 0 %/% 10
[1] 0
> 30 %% 10
[1] 0
> 35 %/% 10
[1] 3
> 35 %% 10
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 46):

In R, you can assign your own operators using `%[characters]%`. A trivial example:

```
'%p%' <- function(x, y){x^2 + y}

2 %p% 3 # result: 7
```

While I agree with BlueTrin that `%%` is pretty standard, I have a suspicion `%/%` may have something to do with the sort of operator definitions I showed above - perhaps it was easier to implement, and makes sense: `%/%` means do a special sort of division (integer division)

Answer (score 38):

Have a look at the examples below for a clearer understanding of the differences between the different operators:

```
> # Floating Division:
> 5/2
[1] 2.5
> 
> # Integer Division:
> 5%/%2
[1] 2
> 
> # Remainder:
> 5%%2
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 11):

I think it is because `%` has often be associated with the modulus operator in many programming languages.

It is the case, e.g., in C, C++, C# and Java, and many other languages which derive their syntax from C (C itself took it from B).

Comment: This, plus Edward's answer: the percent sign is widely used as modulus, and in R it's easy to make your own operator that is bracketed by percent signs.